# url() parameter not working in Blade template include

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5 with Blade templates.  My templates look like so:

**drone.blade.php**

```
@include('drone.gallery')
```

**drone/gallery.php**

```
{{ url('images-gallery/DSC_0072.JPG') }}
```

However, the `url()` function does not work inside my include file.  If I copy the `{{ url('images-gallery/DSC_0072.JPG') }}` line into **drone.blade.php** it works as expected.

Why is the `url()` parameter not working inside include?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see your filename is gallery.php.

Can you plaese change it to gallery.blade.php

Comment: Was this helpful?